# Updated book or review paper on MCMC methods (2022)

Tags: self-study, bayesian, references, markov-chain-montecarlo

For a self-study course, I'm looking for bibliography that describes current MCMC algorithms. I'd prefer a book or a review paper.

My background knowledge is at the level of [Gamerman-Lopes](https://www.routledge.com/Markov-Chain-Monte-Carlo-Stochastic-Simulation-for-Bayesian-Inference/Gamerman-Lopes/p/book/9781584885870) or [Gilks-Richardson-Spiegelhalter](https://www.routledge.com/Markov-Chain-Monte-Carlo-in-Practice/Gilks-Richardson-Spiegelhalter/p/book/9780412055515) and I will read [Liu](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-76371-2) soon, but I'd like to find other good updated material that will help me understand the current directions of research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The Hastings algorithm at fifty, by Dunson & Johndrow, [Biometrika](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article-abstract/107/1/1/5686745?login=false), 2020
2. [Computational Bayesian Statistics](https://amzn.to/3LeuISr): An Introduction by Carlos Daniel Paulino, M. Antónia Amaral Turkman, & Peter Muller [CRC Press](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi3_a7j-JP6AhVPy6QKHUOZB-8Qzo4CKAB6BAgqEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbooks.google.com%2Fbooks%2Fabout%2FComputational_Bayesian_Statistics.html%3Fid%3Dd4KFDwAAQBAJ%26printsec%3Dfrontcover%26source%3Dkp_read_button%26hl%3Den&usg=AOvVaw0cBzAyKwCXnfLuSOOLETiN), 2020
3. Accelerating MCMC algorithms by Christian Robert, Víctor Elvira, Nick Tawn, & Changye Wu, in [Wiley Interdisciplinary Reviews: Computational Statistics](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01961128), 2018
4. Markov Chain Monte Carlo Methods, a [survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.06249v1.pdf)
   with some frequent misunderstandings by Christian P. Robert & Wu Changye,  in Wiley StatsRef: Statistics Reference Online, 2020 *[where I reproduced some Q&A's from Cross Validated]*
5. [Handbook of Markov Chain Monte Carlo](https://amzn.to/3RKPUBW) by Steve Brooks, Andrew Gelman, Galin Jones  & Xiao-Li Meng, 2011 *[still relevant, see, e.g., the chapter on HMC]*

Comment: Thanks!! May I ask what you think of parallel MCMC techniques and the "quantum future" of MCMC?

Comment: I have no opinion about quantum MCMC at this stage.